# Sortable tableview in android

Tags: android, android-studio, uitableview, android-tablelayout

I am unable to understand the code of **comparator** mentioned in the following GitHub library.

Can someone explain the **comparator** code better?

Please upload your sample code of the **comparator** so that it would be better for me to understand.

If you need to make your data sortable, you should use the **SortableTableView** instead of the ordinary **TableView**. To make a table sortable by a column, all you need to do is to implement a **Comparator** and set it to the specific column.

Code of comparator:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // ...
    sortableTableView.setColumnComparator(0, new CarProducerComparator());
}

private static class CarProducerComparator implements Comparator<Car> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Car car1, Car car2) {
        return car1.getProducer().getName().compareTo(car2.getProducer().getName());
    }
}
```

By doing so the SortableTableView will automatically display a sortable indicator next to the table header of the column with the index 0. By clicking this table header, the table is sorted ascending with the given Comparator. If the table header is clicked again, it will be sorted in descending order.

GitHub link:
https://github.com/ISchwarz23/SortableTableView

Answer (score 1):

this is original source code of `java.util.Comparator` that used in that library you can see what is happening and i think car1 and car2 represent of a row and next row to it to compare. just hold `ctrl` and click on any method you can't understand that will drive you to the source code.

```
    /*
 * Copyright (c) 1997, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
 * DO NOT ALTER OR REMOVE COPYRIGHT NOTICES OR THIS FILE HEADER.
 *
 * This code is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
 * under the terms of the GNU General Public License version 2 only, as
 * published by the Free Software Foundation.  Oracle designates this
 * particular file as subject to the "Classpath" exception as provided
 * by Oracle in the LICENSE file that accompanied this code.
 *
 * This code is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT
 * ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU General Public License
 * version 2 for more details (a copy is included in the LICENSE file that
 * accompanied this code).
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License version
 * 2 along with this work; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation,
 * Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301 USA.
 *
 * Please contact Oracle, 500 Oracle Parkway, Redwood Shores, CA 94065 USA
 * or visit www.oracle.com if you need additional information or have any
 * questions.
 */

package java.util;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.ToIntFunction;
import java.util.function.ToLongFunction;
import java.util.function.ToDoubleFunction;
import java.util.Comparators;

/**
 * A comparison function, which imposes a <i>total ordering</i> on some
 * collection of objects.  Comparators can be passed to a sort method (such
 * as {@link Collections#sort(List,Comparator) Collections.sort} or {@link
 * Arrays#sort(Object[],Comparator) Arrays.sort}) to allow precise control
 * over the sort order.  Comparators can also be used to control the order of
 * certain data structures (such as {@link SortedSet sorted sets} or {@link
 * SortedMap sorted maps}), or to provide an ordering for collections of
 * objects that don't have a {@link Comparable natural ordering}.<p>
 *
 * The ordering imposed by a comparator <tt>c</tt> on a set of elements
 * <tt>S</tt> is said to be <i>consistent with equals</i> if and only if
 * <tt>c.compare(e1, e2)==0</tt> has the same boolean value as
 * <tt>e1.equals(e2)</tt> for every <tt>e1</tt> and <tt>e2</tt> in
 * <tt>S</tt>.<p>
 *
 * Caution should be exercised when using a comparator capable of imposing an
 * ordering inconsistent with equals to order a sorted set (or sorted map).
 * Suppose a sorted set (or sorted map) with an explicit comparator <tt>c</tt>
 * is used with elements (or keys) drawn from a set <tt>S</tt>.  If the
 * ordering imposed by <tt>c</tt> on <tt>S</tt> is inconsistent with equals,
 * the sorted set (or sorted map) will behave "strangely."  In particular the
 * sorted set (or sorted map) will violate the general contract for set (or
 * map), which is defined in terms of <tt>equals</tt>.<p>
 *
 * For example, suppose one adds two elements {@code a} and {@code b} such that
 * {@code (a.equals(b) && c.compare(a, b) != 0)}
 * to an empty {@code TreeSet} with comparator {@code c}.
 * The second {@code add} operation will return
 * true (and the size of the tree set will increase) because {@code a} and
 * {@code b} are not equivalent from the tree set's perspective, even though
 * this is contrary to the specification of the
 * {@link Set#add Set.add} method.<p>
 *
 * Note: It is generally a good idea for comparators to also implement
 * <tt>java.io.Serializable</tt>, as they may be used as ordering methods in
 * serializable data structures (like {@link TreeSet}, {@link TreeMap}).  In
 * order for the data structure to serialize successfully, the comparator (if
 * provided) must implement <tt>Serializable</tt>.<p>
 *
 * For the mathematically inclined, the <i>relation</i> that defines the
 * <i>imposed ordering</i> that a given comparator <tt>c</tt> imposes on a
 * given set of objects <tt>S</tt> is:<pre>
 *       {(x, y) such that c.compare(x, y) &lt;= 0}.
 * </pre> The <i>quotient</i> for this total order is:<pre>
 *       {(x, y) such that c.compare(x, y) == 0}.
 * </pre>
 *
 * It follows immediately from the contract for <tt>compare</tt> that the
 * quotient is an <i>equivalence relation</i> on <tt>S</tt>, and that the
 * imposed ordering is a <i>total order</i> on <tt>S</tt>.  When we say that
 * the ordering imposed by <tt>c</tt> on <tt>S</tt> is <i>consistent with
 * equals</i>, we mean that the quotient for the ordering is the equivalence
 * relation defined by the objects' {@link Object#equals(Object)
 * equals(Object)} method(s):<pre>
 *     {(x, y) such that x.equals(y)}. </pre>
 *
 * <p>Unlike {@code Comparable}, a comparator may optionally permit
 * comparison of null arguments, while maintaining the requirements for
 * an equivalence relation.
 *
 * <p>This interface is a member of the
 * <a href="{@docRoot}openjdk-redirect.html?v=8&path=/technotes/guides/collections/index.html">
 * Java Collections Framework</a>.
 *
 * @param <T> the type of objects that may be compared by this comparator
 *
 * @author  Josh Bloch
 * @author  Neal Gafter
 * @see Comparable
 * @see java.io.Serializable
 * @since 1.2
 */
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Comparator<T> {
    /**
     * Compares its two arguments for order.  Returns a negative integer,
     * zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal
     * to, or greater than the second.<p>
     *
     * In the foregoing description, the notation
     * <tt>sgn(</tt><i>expression</i><tt>)</tt> designates the mathematical
     * <i>signum</i> function, which is defined to return one of <tt>-1</tt>,
     * <tt>0</tt>, or <tt>1</tt> according to whether the value of
     * <i>expression</i> is negative, zero or positive.<p>
     *
     * The implementor must ensure that <tt>sgn(compare(x, y)) ==
     * -sgn(compare(y, x))</tt> for all <tt>x</tt> and <tt>y</tt>.  (This
     * implies that <tt>compare(x, y)</tt> must throw an exception if and only
     * if <tt>compare(y, x)</tt> throws an exception.)<p>
     *
     * The implementor must also ensure that the relation is transitive:
     * <tt>((compare(x, y)&gt;0) &amp;&amp; (compare(y, z)&gt;0))</tt> implies
     * <tt>compare(x, z)&gt;0</tt>.<p>
     *
     * Finally, the implementor must ensure that <tt>compare(x, y)==0</tt>
     * implies that <tt>sgn(compare(x, z))==sgn(compare(y, z))</tt> for all
     * <tt>z</tt>.<p>
     *
     * It is generally the case, but <i>not</i> strictly required that
     * <tt>(compare(x, y)==0) == (x.equals(y))</tt>.  Generally speaking,
     * any comparator that violates this condition should clearly indicate
     * this fact.  The recommended language is "Note: this comparator
     * imposes orderings that are inconsistent with equals."
     *
     * @param o1 the first object to be compared.
     * @param o2 the second object to be compared.
     * @return a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the
     *         first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the
     *         second.
     * @throws NullPointerException if an argument is null and this
     *         comparator does not permit null arguments
     * @throws ClassCastException if the arguments' types prevent them from
     *         being compared by this comparator.
     */
    int compare(T o1, T o2);

    /**
     * Indicates whether some other object is &quot;equal to&quot; this
     * comparator.  This method must obey the general contract of
     * {@link Object#equals(Object)}.  Additionally, this method can return
     * <tt>true</tt> <i>only</i> if the specified object is also a comparator
     * and it imposes the same ordering as this comparator.  Thus,
     * <code>comp1.equals(comp2)</code> implies that <tt>sgn(comp1.compare(o1,
     * o2))==sgn(comp2.compare(o1, o2))</tt> for every object reference
     * <tt>o1</tt> and <tt>o2</tt>.<p>
     *
     * Note that it is <i>always</i> safe <i>not</i> to override
     * <tt>Object.equals(Object)</tt>.  However, overriding this method may,
     * in some cases, improve performance by allowing programs to determine
     * that two distinct comparators impose the same order.
     *
     * @param   obj   the reference object with which to compare.
     * @return  <code>true</code> only if the specified object is also
     *          a comparator and it imposes the same ordering as this
     *          comparator.
     * @see Object#equals(Object)
     * @see Object#hashCode()
     */
    boolean equals(Object obj);

    /**
     * Returns a comparator that imposes the reverse ordering of this
     * comparator.
     *
     * @return a comparator that imposes the reverse ordering of this
     *         comparator.
     * @since 1.8
     */
    default Comparator<T> reversed() {
        return Collections.reverseOrder(this);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a lexicographic-order comparator with another comparator.
     * If this {@code Comparator} considers two elements equal, i.e.
     * {@code compare(a, b) == 0}, {@code other} is used to determine the order.
     *
     * <p>The returned comparator is serializable if the specified comparator
     * is also serializable.
     *
     * @apiNote
     * For example, to sort a collection of {@code String} based on the length
     * and then case-insensitive natural ordering, the comparator can be
     * composed using following code,
     *
     * <pre>{@code
     *     Comparator<String> cmp = Comparator.comparingInt(String::length)
     *             .thenComparing(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
     * }</pre>
     *
     * @param  other the other comparator to be used when this comparator
     *         compares two objects that are equal.
     * @return a lexicographic-order comparator composed of this and then the
     *         other comparator
     * @throws NullPointerException if the argument is null.
     * @since 1.8
     */
    default Comparator<T> thenComparing(Comparator<? super T> other) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(other);
        return (Comparator<T> & Serializable) (c1, c2) -> {
            int res = compare(c1, c2);
            return (res != 0) ? res : other.compare(c1, c2);
        };
    }

    /**
     * Returns a lexicographic-order comparator with a function that
     * extracts a key to be compared with the given {@code Comparator}.
     *
     * @implSpec This default implementation behaves as if {@code
     *           thenComparing(comparing(keyExtractor, cmp))}.
     *
     * @param  <U>  the type of the sort key
     * @param  keyExtractor the function used to extract the sort key
     * @param  keyComparator the {@code Comparator} used to compare the sort key
     * @return a lexicographic-order comparator composed of this comparator
     *         and then comparing on the key extracted by the keyExtractor function
     * @throws NullPointerException if either argument is null.
     * @see #comparing(Function, Comparator)
     * @see #thenComparing(Comparator)
     * @since 1.8
     */
    default <U> Comparator<T> thenComparing(
            Function<? super T, ? extends U> keyExtractor,
            Comparator<? super U> keyComparator)
    {
        return thenComparing(comparing(keyExtractor, keyComparator));
    }

    /**
     * Returns a lexicographic-order comparator with a function that
     * extracts a {@code Comparable} sort key.
     *
     * @implSpec This default implementation behaves as if {@code
     *           thenComparing(comparing(keyExtractor))}.
     *
     * @param  <U>  the type of the {@link Comparable} sort key
     * @param  keyExtractor the function used to extract the {@link
     *         Comparable} sort key
     * @return a lexicographic-order comparator composed of this and then the
     *         {@link Comparable} sort key.
     * @throws NullPointerException if the argument is null.
     * @see #comparing(Function)
     * @see #thenComparing(Comparator)
     * @since 1.8
     */
    default <U extends Comparable<? super U>> Comparator<T> thenComparing(
            Function<? super T, ? extends U> keyExtractor)
    {
        return thenComparing(comparing(keyExtractor));
    }

    /**
     * Returns a lexicographic-order comparator with a function that
     * extracts a {@code int} sort key.
     *
     * @implSpec This default implementation behaves as if {@code
     *           thenComparing(comparingInt(keyExtractor))}.
     *
     * @param  keyExtractor the function used to extract the integer sort key
     * @return a lexicographic-order comparator composed of this and then the
     *         {@code int} sort key
     * @throws NullPointerException if the argument is null.
     * @see #comparingInt(ToIntFunction)
     * @see #thenComparing(Comparator)
     * @since 1.8
     */
    default Comparator<T> thenComparingInt(ToIntFunction<? super T> keyExtractor) {
        return thenComparing(comparingInt(keyExtractor));
    }

    /**
     * Returns a lexicographic-order comparator with a function that
     * extracts a {@code long} sort key.
     *
     * @implSpec This default implementation behaves as if {@code
     *           thenComparing(comparingLong(keyExtractor))}.
     *
     * @param  keyExtractor the function used to extract the long sort key
     * @return a lexicographic-order comparator composed of this and then the
     *         {@code long} sort key
     * @throws NullPointerException if the argument is null.
     * @see #comparingLong(ToLongFunction)
     * @see #thenComparing(Comparator)
     * @since 1.8
     */
    default Comparator<T> thenComparingLong(ToLongFunction<? super T> keyExtractor) {
        return thenComparing(comparingLong(keyExtractor));
    }

    /**
     * Returns a lexicographic-order comparator with a function that
     * extracts a {@code double} sort key.
     *
     * @implSpec This default implementation behaves as if {@code
     *           thenComparing(comparingDouble(keyExtractor))}.
     *
     * @param  keyExtractor the function used to extract the double sort key
     * @return a lexicographic-order comparator composed of this and then the
     *         {@code double} sort key
     * @throws NullPointerException if the argument is null.
     * @see #comparingDouble(ToDoubleFunction)
     * @see #thenComparing(Comparator)
     * @since 1.8
     */
    default Comparator<T> thenComparingDouble(ToDoubleFunction<? super T> keyExtractor) {
        return thenComparing(comparingDouble(keyExtractor));
    }

    /**
     * Returns a comparator that imposes the reverse of the <em>natural
     * ordering</em>.
     *
     * <p>The returned comparator is serializable and throws {@link
     * NullPointerException} when comparing {@code null}.
     *
     * @param  <T> the {@link Comparable} type of element to be compared
     * @return a comparator that imposes the reverse of the <i>natural
     *         ordering</i> on {@code Comparable} objects.
     * @see Comparable
     * @since 1.8
     */
    public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> Comparator<T> reverseOrder() {
        return Collections.reverseOrder();
    }

    /**
     * Returns a comparator that compares {@link Comparable} objects in natural
     * order.
     *
     * <p>The returned comparator is serializable and throws {@link
     * NullPointerException} when comparing {@code null}.
     *
     * @param  <T> the {@link Comparable} type of element to be compared
     * @return a comparator that imposes the <i>natural ordering</i> on {@code
     *         Comparable} objects.
     * @see Comparable
     * @since 1.8
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> Comparator<T> naturalOrder() {
        return (Comparator<T>) Comparators.NaturalOrderComparator.INSTANCE;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a null-friendly comparator that considers {@code null} to be
     * less than non-null. When both are {@code null}, they are considered
     * equal. If both are non-null, the specified {@code Comparator} is used
     * to determine the order. If the specified comparator is {@code null},
     * then the returned comparator considers all non-null values to be equal.
     *
     * <p>The returned comparator is serializable if the specified comparator
     * is serializable.
     *
     * @param  <T> the type of the elements to be compared
     * @param  comparator a {@code Comparator} for comparing non-null values
     * @return a comparator that considers {@code null} to be less than
     *         non-null, and compares non-null objects with the supplied
     *         {@code Comparator}.
     * @since 1.8
     */
    public static <T> Comparator<T> nullsFirst(Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
        return new Comparators.NullComparator<>(true, comparator);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a null-friendly comparator that considers {@code null} to be
     * greater than non-null. When both are {@code null}, they are considered
     * equal. If both are non-null, the specified {@code Comparator} is used
     * to determine the order. If the specified comparator is {@code null},
     * then the returned comparator considers all non-null values to be equal.
     *
     * <p>The returned comparator is serializable if the specified comparator
     * is serializable.
     *
     * @param  <T> the type of the elements to be compared
     * @param  comparator a {@code Comparator} for comparing non-null values
     * @return a comparator that considers {@code null} to be greater than
     *         non-null, and compares non-null objects with the supplied
     *         {@code Comparator}.
     * @since 1.8
     */
    public static <T> Comparator<T> nullsLast(Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
        return new Comparators.NullComparator<>(false, comparator);
    }

    /**
     * Accepts a function that extracts a sort key from a type {@code T}, and
     * returns a {@code Comparator<T>} that compares by that sort key using
     * the specified {@link Comparator}.
      *
     * <p>The returned comparator is serializable if the specified function
     * and comparator are both serializable.
     *
     * @apiNote
     * For example, to obtain a {@code Comparator} that compares {@code
     * Person} objects by their last name ignoring case differences,
     *
     * <pre>{@code
     *     Comparator<Person> cmp = Comparator.comparing(
     *             Person::getLastName,
     *             String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
     * }</pre>
     *
     * @param  <T> the type of element to be compared
     * @param  <U> the type of the sort key
     * @param  keyExtractor the function used to extract the sort key
     * @param  keyComparator the {@code Comparator} used to compare the sort key
     * @return a comparator that compares by an extracted key using the
     *         specified {@code Comparator}
     * @throws NullPointerException if either argument is null
     * @since 1.8
     */
    public static <T, U> Comparator<T> comparing(
            Function<? super T, ? extends U> keyExtractor,
            Comparator<? super U> keyComparator)
    {
        Objects.requireNonNull(keyExtractor);
        Objects.requireNonNull(keyComparator);
        return (Comparator<T> & Serializable)
            (c1, c2) -> keyComparator.compare(keyExtractor.apply(c1),
                                              keyExtractor.apply(c2));
    }

    /**
     * Accepts a function that extracts a {@link java.lang.Comparable
     * Comparable} sort key from a type {@code T}, and returns a {@code
     * Comparator<T>} that compares by that sort key.
     *
     * <p>The returned comparator is serializable if the specified function
     * is also serializable.
     *
     * @apiNote
     * For example, to obtain a {@code Comparator} that compares {@code
     * Person} objects by their last name,
     *
     * <pre>{@code
     *     Comparator<Person> byLastName = Comparator.comparing(Person::getLastName);
     * }</pre>
     *
     * @param  <T> the type of element to be compared
     * @param  <U> the type of the {@code Comparable} sort key
     * @param  keyExtractor the function used to extract the {@link
     *         Comparable} sort key
     * @return a comparator that compares by an extracted key
     * @throws NullPointerException if the argument is null
     * @since 1.8
     */
    public static <T, U extends Comparable<? super U>> Comparator<T> comparing(
            Function<? super T, ? extends U> keyExtractor)
    {
        Objects.requireNonNull(keyExtractor);
        return (Comparator<T> & Serializable)
            (c1, c2) -> keyExtractor.apply(c1).compareTo(keyExtractor.apply(c2));
    }

    /**
     * Accepts a function that extracts an {@code int} sort key from a type
     * {@code T}, and returns a {@code Comparator<T>} that compares by that
     * sort key.
     *
     * <p>The returned comparator is serializable if the specified function
     * is also serializable.
     *
     * @param  <T> the type of element to be compared
     * @param  keyExtractor the function used to extract the integer sort key
     * @return a comparator that compares by an extracted key
     * @see #comparing(Function)
     * @throws NullPointerException if the argument is null
     * @since 1.8
     */
    public static <T> Comparator<T> comparingInt(ToIntFunction<? super T> keyExtractor) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(keyExtractor);
        return (Comparator<T> & Serializable)
            (c1, c2) -> Integer.compare(keyExtractor.applyAsInt(c1), keyExtractor.applyAsInt(c2));
    }

    /**
     * Accepts a function that extracts a {@code long} sort key from a type
     * {@code T}, and returns a {@code Comparator<T>} that compares by that
     * sort key.
     *
     * <p>The returned comparator is serializable if the specified function is
     * also serializable.
     *
     * @param  <T> the type of element to be compared
     * @param  keyExtractor the function used to extract the long sort key
     * @return a comparator that compares by an extracted key
     * @see #comparing(Function)
     * @throws NullPointerException if the argument is null
     * @since 1.8
     */
    public static <T> Comparator<T> comparingLong(ToLongFunction<? super T> keyExtractor) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(keyExtractor);
        return (Comparator<T> & Serializable)
            (c1, c2) -> Long.compare(keyExtractor.applyAsLong(c1), keyExtractor.applyAsLong(c2));
    }

    /**
     * Accepts a function that extracts a {@code double} sort key from a type
     * {@code T}, and returns a {@code Comparator<T>} that compares by that
     * sort key.
     *
     * <p>The returned comparator is serializable if the specified function
     * is also serializable.
     *
     * @param  <T> the type of element to be compared
     * @param  keyExtractor the function used to extract the double sort key
     * @return a comparator that compares by an extracted key
     * @see #comparing(Function)
     * @throws NullPointerException if the argument is null
     * @since 1.8
     */
    public static<T> Comparator<T> comparingDouble(ToDoubleFunction<? super T> keyExtractor) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(keyExtractor);
        return (Comparator<T> & Serializable)
            (c1, c2) -> Double.compare(keyExtractor.applyAsDouble(c1), keyExtractor.applyAsDouble(c2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can u please post a sample code of sortable tableview where a comparator is used

Comment: https://github.com/ISchwarz23/SortableTableView/tree/master/app/src/main/java/de/codecrafters this is example project from the library you can read it